# Quartzcore Framework Error iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation

I have been using the quartz core framework in my iOS application for a while now. Just recently, without any changes to the framework, it has caused a build error in my application. In the CATransform3d.h header file, two build errors have been found. The code with the errors is the following.

```
@interface NSValue (CATransform3DAdditions) - Method type specifier must start with + or -

+ (NSValue *)valueWithCATransform3D:(CATransform3D)t; - expected selector for objective c method

@end

- (CATransform3D)CATransform3DValue;
```

Does anyone have any idea why the following build errors may be occurring? Why would they just appear out of nowhere? I have deleted and re-added quartz core framework. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you just update to Xcode 4.4?

Comment: It has been like this before and after I have updated Xcode

Comment: So the build error was in some specific file of yours? If so then under "Product" you can select "Preprocessed File" and see exactly what the compiler sees. Just for the heck of it I tried adding the header to a random file in my iOS 5.0 app with no error (#import <QuartzCore/CATransform3d.h>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode 4, in the left sidebar, select the project file at the top:

1) Make sure your target is selected in the main view, and you should see 5 tabs at the top,

2) Click the "Build Phases" tab,

3) Click the arrow to the left of the "Link Binary With Libraries" row,

4) Click the plus button that just appeared at the bottom of that row,

5) Type "QuartzCore" into the search field,

6) You should see a folder named "iOS 4.3" with the "QuartzCore.framework" inside of it,

7) Double click the "QuartzCore.framework" to add it to your current project.

Then it should appear in left sidebar, and you can drag it into the frameworks folder if you wish.

Make sure you do a

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```